# actions-on-google has StatusRuntimeException from time to time

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-smart-home

We use actions-on-google library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.actions</groupId>
    <artifactId>actions-on-google</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Our flow includes calling HomeGraphApiServiceGrpc.requestSyncDevices(RequestSyncDevicesRequest request) to Synchronize our devices when something has changed.
Our testers noticed that some requests return StatusRuntimeException and it appears more and more often now.
How can we minimize the occurrence of such an error and what causes it may have?

Comment: Have you verified your [quotas](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/quotas) for testing? You can also check your [logs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/monitoring-logging) to see if there's anything consistently relating to the error occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be going above the [rate limits](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/quotas) for the HomeGraph API (applicable to REST & RPC APIs). Alternatively, there are two ways to issue request sync: synchronous (blocking) and asynchronous. If you are having issues with one of those types, you can try out the other.